# How to make all fields "required" in SQLAlchemyAutoSchema in flask_marshmallow?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemyAutoSchema to automatically generate fields for the model, by default, it sets all fields' *required* status to *False*. How can I make all fields required?

```
class ReferralOuctomeSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = my_model
        dump_only = ("id",)
        required = True
```

Comment: Can't you just make those fields `nullable=False` in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Doesn't apply in this. I just want to apply it on the schema level.

Comment: I don't think there's any marshmallow feature to achieve this. You could iterate on the schema fields and set required. If you don't want to do it manually, it might be achievable with a custom metaclass as a base schema. You may also monkeypatch `Field._validate_missing` (but this sucks).